# Anti-Markovnikov Effect

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, radicals

We have seen that $\ce{HBr}$ shows an anti-Markovnikov effect when it reacts with alkenes in the presence of peroxides. Why does only $\ce{HBr}$ shows this effect? How about the other hydrogen halides $\ce{HX}~(\ce{X} = \ce{F}, \ce{Cl}, \ce{I})$?

Comment: See [here](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/mechanisms/freerad/alkenehbr.html) for detailed discussion or [here](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/markovnikovs-rule.shtm) for brief overview.

Answer (score 5):

Main reason is behind is the reaction mechanism involved. *$\ce{HBr}$* or other halides usually react with alkenes through an [electrophilic addition](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/mechanisms/eladd/symhbr.html). Due to the weak *$\ce{O-O}$* bond, peroxides act as a source of free radicals. Thus in the presence of peroxides, a [free radical chain pathway](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Hydrocarbons/Alkenes/Radical_Additions--Anti-Markovnikov_Product_Formation) is followed.

**The other hydrogen halides are reluctant to this reaction, because [the chain reaction can't proceed due to energy requirements for the generation of the corresponding halogen free radicals](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/mechanisms/freerad/alkenehbr.html).**